# How to find out current version of Outlook from VSTO Addin?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I think my searching skills are terrible today, but I am trying to find out which version of Office Outlook in my add-in running in?

i.e., I need to know if my add-in is running with Outlook 2007 or 2010

Is there any API that I can leverage to find out the current outlook version?

Thanks,
Harsha

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Version
```

Comment: This gives me a version in "16.0.0.XXXX" format but while i see the version under File -> Office Account -> "About Outlook" it shows 16.0.XXXX.XXXX format also doesn't match any part except 16.0, I want to check it's minor version how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

[OL: How to Programmatically Determine the Version of Outlook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238404/en-us).

Comment: That sounds like a pretty neat solution. Additionally, You can also see the version number in the registry (12 / 14 / etc).